# Reading binary integers from a file in C

Tags: c, binary, fread

All night I have been looking for answers for this & haven't slept, yet, I can't make it work...
I have a binary file and I want to read it and take the value of each integer...
Here is some code:

```
FILE *f;
char ch;
char t1[3];
int l, c, grayScale, i, j;
int p =0;


f = fopen(pgm, "rb");

(...)

c = 0;
l = 0;


fscanf(f, "%d", &c);

fscanf(f, "%d", &l);

fscanf(f, "%d", &grayScale);


A = alocar_memoria_matriz(l,c);

for(i = 0; i<l; i++){
    for(j=0; j<c; j++){
        if(fread(&p,sizeof(int),1,f) !=1){
             fprintf(stderr, "\nError!\n");
             fclose(f);
             free_memoria_matriz(A,l);
             return NULL;
        }else if(p>grayScale|| p<0){
            fprintf(stderr, "\nError!\n");
            fclose(f);
            free_memoria_matriz(A,l);
            return NULL;
        }else{
        A[i][j] = (tdf_elemento) p;

    }
}
}
```

I did some `printf` of that p (with %d and %i) and I get values like -1161602550, 1213357911, 994462027...
I really don't know what's going on, I also tried to change p for char[5] but didn't work so far...
Thank you in advance...

Comment: What is the size of integers in the binary file? The `int` type represents a 32-bit integer (signed) but the file may contain 16-bit integers (`short`, or `ushort` for unsigned).

Comment: You are reading at first with fscanf(). Are you sure the file pointer is on the right position after that for reading binary integers?

Comment: The fscanf is ok, there are a magic number, "PX" in ascii and more 3 ints in ascii before the binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "binary" open mode does not change the way `fscanf` parses the file. Its only effect is to (perhaps) prevent conversion of `\r\n` line endings to `\n` as the file is read by stdio facilities.

To read from a stdio file `f` into an integer `i`, you can do `fread( & i, sizeof i, 1, f )`. But note that this does not respect endianness. Without explicit byte-swapping your binary format will be platform-dependent on endianness.

Comment: The fscanf is ok, there are a magic number, "PX" in ascii and more 3 ints in ascii before the binary, the rows, columns and the gray scale and comes in ascii

Comment: @JoãoSilva If this solved the problem at hand, please accept it. If there's another issue, please open a new question.

Comment: It didn't solve, but tomorrow I will meet my teacher for he solve it... Thank you for the help